# Printing to file using Gecode

Tags: c++

I am doing a Gecode project and the code should output a file which looks like the following:

```
n: 17
x: {0, 0, 16, 18, 17, 31, 32, 0, 34, 10, 30, 37, 38, 30, 30, 10}
y: {0, 27, 28, 14, 0, 31, 20, 17, 11, 17, 0, 0, 6, 7, 11, 25}
s: 43
runtime: 0.137
failure: 127
```

The above is an example of what the code should output. I have tried to do the following code:

```
virtual void
print(std::ostream& os) const {
    string filename = "project1-t15-n" + n + ".txt";

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (filename);

    myfile << "n: " << n << std::endl;
    myfile << "x: {";
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            myfile << ", ";
        }
        myfile << x[i];
    }
    myfile << "}" << std::endl;
    myfile << "y: {";
    for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            myfile << ", ";
        }
        myfile << y[i];
    }
    myfile << "}" << std::endl;
    myfile << "s: " << s << std::endl;

    //???????????????????????????????? print runtime and failures

    myfile.close();
}
```

I know that n, s, x and y are correct, but I have two questions:

1: Is `print(std::ostream& os) const` the correct usage when printing to a file?

2: How can you get runtime and failures from the Gecode output? Their build in print function does this.

Comment: I don't understand, your passing an `ostream` to `print()` and not using it.  Maybe you want to create the files stream outside of `print()` and pass it to `print()`.

Comment: I think the important thing is that I have to use the print function to print to a file. Since I have never printed do a file before inside a print function I'm not sure how to do it. All I know is that when you want the print function to print to the terminal, you do it like above, or so I have been tought. An example can bee seen at [link](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/magic-square_8cpp_source.html) but that example only writes to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myfile << "s: " << s << std::endl;` I don't see any `s` in your code, what is it? Also, the signature of your print method says it's already getting the output stream. Is this true? Who calls it, from where and with which arguments? If some other method really calls print and gives it the output stream, then you are probably supposed to use it, instead of creating your own.

UPDATE: had a look at the docs for Gecode, found where print() was defined:

http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/driver_8hh_source.html#l00666

So it is OK for you to redefine this method in your own class which descends from ScriptBase (I guess that's how you are supposed to write the stuff for Gecode), but you should use the provided argument, i.e.:

```
    virtual void
    print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "n: " << n << std::endl;
        os << "x: {";
// etc
```

One option to actually print to specific file i/o console is simply run your program with rerouted output. E.g. if your program is called myprogram and your file is called myfile.txt, run it as:

```
myprogram >> myfile.txt
```

and it will print everything to the file instead of console.

Also, as far as the docs ( http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf ) say, if you have ScriptBase-derived class S, you can call its method S->print() directly from your main() method, and supply the right file stream there, i.e:

```
S* s= new S; // something like that
ofstream f("myfile.txt");
s->print(f);
...
```

Comment: The variables s, n are set earlier in the code (not relevant here), and same with the arrays x and y. This function prints those variables correctly. The most important question is how to print runtime and failures.

When normally writing a Gecode program, you don't call the print function, it is just there. There are two problems with this. The task specifically states that we have to output something else than is normally output from the biuld in function. And we have to write directly to a file with a specific name instead of the terminal.

Comment: Are you told to write a replacement for that print() function? In any case, who is going to call your function and from where?

Comment: Is starting your program and then rerouting output to a file not an option? like `<yourprogram> >> <yourfilename>`

Comment: When using Gecode in it's simplest way, you don't even have a print function visible, and you don't call it somewhere in the cpp-file. It's just there magically somehow, our teacher hasn't explained it afaik. The built in print function outputs something very different from what we are supposed to print, but it does print the two things I need, namely failures and runtime. But since I havn't been able to find the built in function, i don't know where it get those values.

Comment: As far as I could understand from the examples and the docs, the print() method is present in every Script (and you are also creating a Script). It's a virtual method in ScriptBase class: http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/driver_8hh_source.html#l00666 So it makes sense to redefine it to make sure it prints what you want, but make it use the parameter you are provided. (Will also say it in the answer)

Comment: This is from our task description: The resulting program must be called squarepacking.cpp and take a number n of squares as command-line argument. For team t, the report must be called project1-tt-report.pdf and the command-line call squarepacking n must produce a textfile called project1-tt-nn.txt with the first solution, which has the structure of the sample file http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/consprog/ht13/homeworks/project1-t9-n17.txt (but not necessarily the same contents for n = 17), the runtime being expressed in seconds. Therefore I don't think that rerouting output is enough.

Comment: Then you can just call the print method yourself and supply it the file stream from main. If you make sure that your print method uses the supplied argument, this should also work.